# Java integer multiply error: 1052254545 * 10=1932610858, Why?

Tags: java

I've a java File: Int.java

```
class Int {
   public static void main(String[] args){
        int i=1052254545;
        System.out.println(i* 10);
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

I run it:

```
$java Int
1932610858
1052254545
```

Why? and How to correct?

Comment: Are you aware of `Integer.MAX_INT` ?

Comment: You should use BigInteger in this case.

Comment: Try `System.out.println(i* 10L);`

Answer (score 2):

```
    int i=1052254545;
    System.out.println(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    System.out.println(i* 10);
    System.out.println(i);
```

Run this.. you will have the answer.

`i*10` > maximum value of `int`

Now In `Java` you can't represent `i*10` value *correctly* since it is out of `int` value range. If you try to represent a value witch not fall into range that will cause truncation of data.